# Missing requirement: Embedded Maven Runtime Bundle when updating Maven

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse

Maven projects do not work under Eclipse Indigo (I have many Indigos and Maven works everywhere except one Indigo instance).

If create new quickstart maven project, then POM file causes an error

```
Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3:resources (execution: default-resources, phase: process-resources)
    - Plugin execution not covered by lifecycle configuration: org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.4.3:testResources (execution: default-testResources, phase: process-test-
     resources)
```

This marks the line

```
<packaging>jar</packaging>
```

No fixes suggested.

If trying to update maven, then the following error occurs:

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
  Software being installed: m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse 1.4.0.20130601-0317 (org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group 1.4.0.20130601-0317)
  Missing requirement: Embedded Maven Runtime Bundle 1.4.0.20130531-2315 (org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime 1.4.0.20130531-2315) requires 'bundle org.slf4j.api 1.6.2' but it could not be found
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: m2e - Maven Integration for Eclipse 1.4.0.20130601-0317 (org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group 1.4.0.20130601-0317)
    To: org.eclipse.m2e.maven.indexer [1.4.0.20130531-2315]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Maven / Nexus Indexer Bundle 1.4.0.20130531-2315 (org.eclipse.m2e.maven.indexer 1.4.0.20130531-2315)
    To: bundle org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime [1.4.0,1.5.0)
```

How to overcome the hell?